# Keychain access very slow after certificate problems

Tags: mac, certificate, keychain, keychain-access

I have a MacBookPro. one day updates started refusing to install because it said the certificate is missing or invalid and someone is doing a man in the middle on me. Same thing went for the Mac App Store - nothing won't install because of certificate invalid. Also xCode was refusing to sign my apps for the iPhone test deployment anymore.
I used a suggestion to start a new admin account and everything worked (updates, app store and xcode) but I liked my old and customized user. So I backed up the keychain from the old user (`/Users/olduser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`) and moved the key keychain from the new user to there, setting the owner(using `chown`) to the old user. And everything started working on the new user, except the keychain access. The keychain access takes about 5 minuts now to load the `login` keychain after I select it, while `System` keychain is working immediately. `login` keychain works correctly after the 5 minuts.
These 5 minuts are annoying, is there any way to make it work immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow directions in this Apple KB article: [Solving problems with keychains](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/9081.html)

If that doesn't make a difference, you can create a new keychain and transfer the passwords into it.

Comment: The latter being incredibly painful... He should consider first changing the keychain passwords temporarily to a single character.

Comment: consider doing what?